Es correcto decir: me sabes como tratar?
Escribí un texto pero después de publicarlo me di cuenta de esa oración, y no se si es correcto

Lo correcto es: sabes como tratarme.

Sabes cómo tratarme,  con tilde en la "o"

So this does not go unanswered I use the comments of @Danielillo and @Gustavson
It should be

Sabes cómo tratarme

To see why ask yourself is it knowing me or treating me? Clearly it is treating me so the pronoun belongs with tratar not saber.

I agree. However, the problem is "cómo", since we can say "me sabes tratar" even if "me" continues to attach to "tratar".

With verb phrases including an infinitive or a gerund, the pronoun functioning as an object can be placed at the beginning, i.e. before the main verb, or after the infinitive or gerund.

Me sabes tratar = Sabes tratarme

Me quieres convencer = Quieres convencerme

Me sigues molestando = Sigues molestándome

Me vienes diciendo = Vienes diciéndome


The problem is that when an infinitive clause is used, introduced by words like qué, cómo, cuándo, dónde, then the initial position is not allowed (the connection with the main verb has been lost) and the pronoun needs to attach to the infinitive it actually refers to:

Sabes cómo tratarme.

Sabes qué decirme.

Sabes dónde llevarme.

Sabes cuándo visitarme.



The reflexive pronouns (me, te, se, nos, os, se) identify who (or what) is performing the action of the verb.

They are usually placed BEFORE the conjugated verb. (Me gusta la música.)

They are attached AFTER the verb:



when the verb is in the INFINITIVE. (¿Sabes cómo tratarme?)
when the verb is conjugated in the positive IMPERATIVE. (Lávate los manos.)


When the verb is conjugated in the GERUND, you have the choice:


to attach it after the verb. (Está lavandose.)
to place it before the conjugated verb. (Se está lavando.)


ChatGPT answer.-

Es correcto decir Me sabes como tratar? No.
Pero creo que solo es un "error" con el pronombre. ¿Cuáles serian unas formas correctas de decirlo?

Sabes cómo tratarme.
Me sabes tratar.

Dicho como lo dijiste, pareciera una frase de alguien que no habla el español como primera lengua y es entendible completamente.
Protip: Siempre puedes decirlo de manera calle (estilo reguetón)

Ya tu sabe! 

